# Forms, Open PDF from URL

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, webview, android-webview

I'm using Xamarin Forms with Android, I need to open a PDF from an URL in my WebView. For some reason, sometime the the Webview is blank. I've searched a lot on Internet and I found some solution that give me the same result, sometime the PDF in the PDF is showed without problem, sometime is a blank page. I'm using "https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" with no results, I'm using this solution ( https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/11/30/open-a-pdf-inside-a-webview-in-xamarin-forms-android/ ) that describe exactly my problem but WebView still show me a blank page sometime.

So, why is so hard to open a PDF Url on Android in a WebView? There is some solution to fix this problem? I don't know what can i else do.

Comment: firstly the reason is that WebView can't open PDF itself. It doesn't support PDF. Your solutions firstly convert PDF into HTML page, and only after that - open that page in WebView. But who knows what can happen during conversion. Try checking logcat for any messages related to WebView.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, bu there is no message related to WebView in my logcat, nothing strange, no crash, nothing. Simply sometime it open the PDF sometime not. Maybe i can try to open the PDF URL with a PDF Reader App installed on my Device? Really I can't understand why on iOS everything works fine and with Android there is not a default PDF Reader. It's insane!

Comment: `open the PDF URL with a PDF Reader App`  is not a good idea I think. It's for the reason that you already know - `there is not a default PDF Reader.` for Android. And it is quite OK not to have it on the device - Windows does not have a PDF reader by default as well. You have to install one.

Comment: I'd suggest implementing PDF reading functionality in your app. There are already tones of libraries.

Comment: Tounes of libraries? Could you please link here some for Xamarin Forms? Thanks!

Comment: sure, using google: `xamarin android pdf` will give you ~5 libraries only on the 1st page.

Comment: Thanks but on Google, all plugins needs an expensive license. I need a free license for this project.

Comment: there are some on github. You don't need any lecense to use a github code. Please take some effort. I don't have to do all research instead of you.

Comment: "Search on Google" is not an answer, but thanks anyway, i found a solution that I will post here soon. ;)

Comment: If I wanted to answer, I would post an **answer**, not a comment. I should not answer questions, which can be solved by simple googling for less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Android WebView not support .pdf file from website, infact, if you try to copy an url with .pdf extension in chrome browser, this will **download the file and open in an app**. So there is no way to show a PDF in an App in a simple way. But there are two solution:

1. On Google there are a lot solutions that tells you to download the PDF and show in an webview, but in my case I can't download a PDF and show.
2. You can write an .html page in your Server that can "wrap" the PDF sended with an URL in GET mode and show it in an .html page without problem ( using jsPDF is an example ) or by using this prefix ( http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url= ) but sometime i give a blank page, so i write my own pdf viewer. In this link ( https://acaliaro.wordpress.com/2017/11/30/open-a-pdf-inside-a-webview-in-xamarin-forms-android/ ) you can find another solution, but for some reason, it still doesn't works. Maybe because I'm on Android 5.0 device.